# VueJS: Updating component collection data from its child

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Given Todo list with filtering:

list.vue:

```
<script>
import TodoItem from './todo_item.vue';
export default {
  components: { TodoItem },
  props: ['selectePriority'],
  data: {
    items: [
      { name: 'Do shopping', priority: 'high' },
      { name: 'Play games', priority: 'low' }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    selectedItems: function() {
      if(this.selectedPriority == 'all') {
        return this.items;
      } else {
        var selectedPriority = this.selectedPriority;
        return this.items.filter(function(item) {
          return item.priority == selectedPriority
        });
      }
    }
  },
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <select v-model="selectedPriority">
      <option value="all">All</option>
      <option value="low">Low</option>
      <option value="high">High</option>
    </select>
    <todo-item
      v-for="item in selectedItems"
      :name="item.name"
      :priority="item.priority"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

todo_item.vue:

```
<script>
export default {
  props: ['name', 'priority']
}
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{ name }}</p>
    <select v-model="priority">
      <option value="low">Low</option>
      <option value="high">High</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>
```

html:

```
<list />
```

Now, when for example filter is set to `all`, I change `Play games` to priority `high` and change filter to `high`, I will see only `Do shopping`, as priority was not updated in `items` collection and it was re-rendered.

What is proper way to update collection data from child components in Vue.js?

Answer (score 0):

computed properties have the ability to create and return a filtered list.

> this example uses [lodash](https://lodash.com/)

```js
data: {
  items: [
    {name: 'thing 1', value: 1000},
    {name: 'thing 2', value: 50},
    {name: 'thing 3', value: 250},
    {name: 'thing 4', value: 342},
  ],
},
computed: {
  orderedItems() {
    let items = []
    return _.orderBy(this.items, 'value', 'desc');
  },
}
```

to update pass the index from orderedItems array into the "this.items" array.

Comment: where should I pass this index?

Answer (score 0):

I found some solution that works - instead of passing all params of todo-item into component, pass whole object:

```
    <todo-item
      v-for="item in selectedItems"
      :item="item"
    />
```

Then object in parent collection is updated automatically.

Is that a good way of doing that in Vue?